# Shared primary key with JPA @MapsId annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

To have shared primary key for a 1<>1 relationship, I'm trying to use JPA @MapsId annotation but I didn't succeed.

Here is my sql table generation :

```
CREATE TABLE `myschema`.`table2` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`coltable2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `myschema`.`table1` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`coltable1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk`
FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
REFERENCES `myschema`.`table2` (`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

And here are my two classes:

Table1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")   
public class Table1 {

@Id 
private int id;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinColumn(name="id")
@MapsId(value="id") 
private Table2 table2;

....

}
```

Table 2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table2")   
public class Table2 {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "table2") 
    private Table1 table1;

    ...

}
```

So when trying to save by doing this:

```
Table1 table1 = new Table1();
table1.setColTable1("table1");      

Table2 table2 = new Table2();
table2.setColTable2("table2");      

table1.setTable2(table2);
table2.setTable1(table1);

dao.save(table1);
```

I get the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

It seems like @MapsId did not propagate id value from table2 identifier to table1 identifier. So the constraint is not respected. But I don't see what's wrong with the code?

Could someone point out my error, please?

Comment: Well I found my mistake, I removed parameter "value" from MapId and it worked. "value"param seems to be used only in case of composite key.

Comment: Hi, there is an example describe how to use @MapsId annotation in one to one bidirectional mapping : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655639/hibernate-class-with-primary-key-that-is-also-a-foreign-key/42662996#42662996

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that `@MapsId` is what you want here.

`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` is probably what you require:

> and it may be used in a OneToOne mapping in which the primary key of
>   the referencing entity is used as a foreign key to the referenced
>   entity.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html

http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/onetoone-with-shared-primary-key.html

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I agree I could use PrimaryKeyJoinColumn but for my understanding this PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation is doing the same job as my JoinColumn with primary keys. My pb is to propagate the identifier value from where it is generated (table2) to where it is should be set (table1). With the same SQL tables I succeeded doing this with the id foreign generator specific to Hibernate. As they said in the Hibernate documentation  "5.1.2.2.7. Identity copy (foreign generator)" it should be possible to do this with JPA annotation MapsId, but I didn't succeed.