# Mapping of primary key as foreign key to another table

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a problem regarding a foreign key relationship and its JPA counterpart.

In the following tables. `means_of_transport` is a table with a consecutive numbering. The other tables have less entries with a mapping of their primary key as a foreign key to the primary key of `means_of_transport`. Sadly, I cannot change the data model.

**Table `means_of_transport`**

```
CREATE TABLE means_of_transport (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    max_capacity INT
);
```

**Table `ocean_ship`**

```
CREATE TABLE ocean_ship (
    means_of_transport_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( means_of_transport_id ) REFERENCES means_of_transport ( id )
);
CREATE INDEX fk_ship_means_of_transport1_idx ON ocean_ship ( means_of_transport_id );
```

There are more tables besides `ocean_ship` with the same key structure but other fields.

**MeansOfTransport.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "means_of_transport")
public class MeansOfTransport extends Model {
    @Id
    public Integer id;
    public Integer maxCapacity;
}
```

**OceanShip.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ocean_ship")
public class OceanShip extends Model {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(table = "means_of_transport", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public MeansOfTransport meansOfTransport;

    public String name;
}
```

Now every time I try to use `OceanShip` in another JPA class as a field, I get this error: `Error reading annotations for models.Classname`.

Am I missing some annotations?

**edit**

Example usage:

```
@ManyToOne
@Column(name = "ocean_ship")
public OceanShip oceanShip;
```

Full stack trace:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.ContainerOrder]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:150) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:114) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:114) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.ContainerOrder
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:54) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1034) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:565) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:252) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:124) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:210) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanTable.createJoinColumn(BeanTable.java:94) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readAssocOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:145) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.parse(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:54) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:45) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1034) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:565) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message came up because some annotations were wrong.

I changed the primary key of `OceanShip` from `MeansOfTransport` to `Integer` and have now to be careful what I enter there. That's the price I have to pay.

Additionally I changed the annotation where I use `OceanShip` from this

```
@ManyToOne
@Column(name = "ocean_ship")
public OceanShip oceanShip;
```

to this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ocean_ship", referencedColumnName = "means_of_transport_id")
public OceanShip oceanCarrierShip;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your DB model is conceptually not right.

It should be something like this below.

The ocean_ship_id is the PK of the ocean_ship table.
And means_of_transport_id from ocean_ship 
is just a FK to the "base" table means_of_transport.

So I would say you get your DB model right, 
then worry about the JPA mapping.

```
CREATE TABLE ocean_ship (
    ocean_ship_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    means_of_transport_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( means_of_transport_id ) REFERENCES means_of_transport ( id )
);
```

Comment: You are right, but sadly I cannot change the data model in any way. I added this to the question. I have to find a way to model it with JPA.

Answer (score 1):

See `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and the ideas given in this thread.

[Shared primary key with JPA @MapsId annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070535/shared-primary-key-with-jpa-mapsid-annotation)

Might be helpful maybe?